# UnboundLocalError: Python

Tags: python-3.x, variable-assignment

I am trying to write a functions for ETS forecast.
Here is my code:

```
# evaluate an ETS model for a given parameters (t,d,s,p,b,r)
def train_ets_model(train, test, cfg):
    t,d,s,p,b,r = cfg
    # prepare training dataset
    history = [x for x in train.values]
    # make predictions
    predictions = list()
    for t in range(len(test.values)):
        model = ExponentialSmoothing(history, trend=t, damped=d, seasonal=s, seasonal_periods=p, use_boxcox=b)
        # fit model
        model_fit = model.fit(optimized=True, remove_bias=r)
        #one-step prediction
        yhat = model_fit.predict(len(history), len(history))[0]
        predictions.append(yhat)
        history.append(test.values[t])
    # calculate out of sample error
    error = np.round(mean_squared_error(test, predictions),2)
    return error, predictions

#evaluate configurations for ETS model
def evaluate_ets_models(train, test, cfg_list):
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for cfg in cfg_list:
        try:
            mse, predictions = train_ets_model(train, test, cfg)
            if mse < best_score:
                best_score, best_cfg = mse, cfg
                #print('ETS%s RMSE=%.3f' % (order,rmse))
        except:
            continue
    return best_cfg, best_score, predictions
    #print('Best ETS%s RMSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, best_score))
```

However, I get an UnboundLocalError:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    Cell In[38], line 1
    ----> 1 evaluate_ets_models(train, test, cfg_list)
    
    Cell In[37], line 32, in evaluate_ets_models(train, test, cfg_list)
         30     except:
         31         continue
    ---> 32 return best_cfg, best_score, predictions

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'predictions' referenced before assignment
```

I have written a similar function for another technique and it works prefectly fine.
Could anyone please advise what do I change to make it work?

Comment: The `cfg_list` you passed to that function is apparently empty; the `for` loop therefore executed zero times, and nothing ever got assigned to `predictions`.  If this is a valid way of calling the function, then you need to give a default value for that variable, just as you did for the other two variables you're returning.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I finally found what was the error. I assigned t as one vales in the tuple cfg_list. but again used 't' in "for t in range(test)"....an oversight from my side and a silly one too. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was an oversight...

```
 def train_ets_model(train, test, cfg):
        **t**,d,s,p,b,r = cfg
        # prepare training dataset
        history = [x for x in train.values]
        # make predictions
        predictions = list()
        **for t in range(len(test.values))**:
```

since t was already assigned earlier, we can't use t again, like in the for loop:

```
for t in range(
```